# How to have /etc/ config files overriden by those found in $HOME/etc/

Tags: linux, debian

I recently crashed my home server, now looking for a more efficient way to do things. I want to use a `/etc` in my `/home/webserver` directory. Which would override the normal `/etc/` files.

Exemple: `/home/webserver/etc/mysql/my.cnf` would override `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Or, if I create a file `~/etc/nanorc`, it would override `/etc/nanorc` etc.

How would I do that under Debian last distrib?

Comment: What is more efficient about that?

Comment: Setup etckeeper.  Clone your /etc repo to another location.

Comment: @Kazark, the ability to "clone" the settings to another box directly ? Keep manual changes separated from bundled stuff ?

Comment: @DavidColl Okay, so you aren't talking about runtime performance. Gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the program doing the configuration handling. E.g. `git` looks for configuration data in several directories in turn, the first found is used. Other programs might just use the first file found in some order, others just use a common configuration.

You could play games with `chroot` and mounting your own `etc` in it, but that will end in a mess that makes me shiver.

Consider carefully *why* each program uses the exact configuration mechanisms it has (no, this isn't random; long, detailed consideration went into each), and see how to *use* it to your advantage, instead of trying to kludge around it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, seems there's no "magic" solution (automatic override). So I setup symbolic links to the fils I've manually modified (ie. /etc/mysql/my.cnf ==points to==> ~/etc/mysql/my.cnf).

Apache2 for exemple, will recursively look into conf directories, that makes the use of symbolic link to a directory possible. Not necessary this way to create a link for each files.